# SQL query select Sequence Number with Min and Max

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

In Firebird server, I want to select rows based on sequence number. For the example I having data like this :

```
ID  ROWNUM
1   A1
2   A2
3   A3
4   NULL
5   NULL
6   A6
```

Query should return

```
A1 - A3, A6
```

I dont figure out how to select the rows, I only can select A1 - A6 but A4 and A5 is in the list even the data is null.

P.S edited sorry, I mean for the firebird server not SQL Server but from the answer that I collected from yesterday, I can get information how to figure out.

Comment: will return 1 row for the result?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu return 1 row and it looks like this " A1 - A3 , A6 " the result have 2 part.. for the sequence line between A1 and A3 also additional number A6 at the end. Is it possible?

Comment: frankly, ID column is of no use for the query, ROWNUM is already pre-sorted

Comment: Are you asking for Microsoft SQL Server, or for Firebird? Why did you tag both?!

Comment: I have re-tagged SQL, as the query language used by Firebird is also SQL.

Answer (score 2):

typical island + gap problem with result in CSV

```
declare @t table (ID int, ROWNUM char(2))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
(1,'A1'),
(2,'A2'),
(3,'A3'),
(4,NULL),
(5,NULL),
(6,'A6');

;with cte as
(
    select  *, grp = ID - row_number() over(order by ROWNUM)
    from    @t
),
cte2 as
(
    select  ROW_NUM = case  when    min(ROWNUM) <> max(ROWNUM)
                then    min(ROWNUM) + ' - ' + max(ROWNUM)
                else    min(ROWNUM)
                end
    from    cte
    where   ROWNUM  is not null
    group by grp
)
select  stuff(
        (select ',' + ROW_NUM
        from    cte2
        for xml path('')),
    1, 1, '')
```

Comment: This will not work for Firebird (the question was originally mistagged), has Firebird has nothing like `stuff`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want separate *max* and *min* range of values

```
select Min(rownum) Minrownum, max(rownum) Maxrownum from (
    select *,
             row_number() over (order by rownum) Seq
    from table) t
where rownum is not null
group by (id- Seq)
```

Comment: Window functions are available in Firebird from version 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

A very close solution to @Squirrel's suggestion, the same logic actually
Basically for identifying [number gaps using SQL](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/find-missing-numbers-gaps-in-sequence-of-numbers-using-sql.aspx)

```
    /*
create table datatbl (ID tinyint identity(1,1), ROWNUM varchar(5))
INSERT INTO datatbl VALUES ('A1'), ('A2'), ('A3'), (NULL), (NULL), ('A6')
*/
;with islands as (
select
    Id,
    RowNum,
    ID - 
    ROW_NUMBER() over (order by 
    (case when ROWNUM is null then null else id end)
    ) grpno
from datatbl
), boundaries as (
select distinct
    grpno, 
    min(id) over (partition by grpno) as minid,
    max(id) over (partition by grpno) as maxid
from islands
where ROWNUM is not null
), fragments as (
select
    b.grpno,
    case when (mi.ROWNUM = ma.ROWNUM) then mi.ROWNUM else mi.ROWNUM + '-' + ma.ROWNUM end as boundary
from boundaries as b
inner join datatbl as mi on mi.ID = b.minid
inner join datatbl as ma on ma.ID = b.maxid
)
select stuff((select ', ' + boundary from fragments for xml path('')),1, 2, '')
```

With SQL Server 2017 instead of For XML Path [string concatenation](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-concatenation-function-to-sql-concatenate-strings.aspx), new [string_agg](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/string-aggregation-function-to-concatenate-in-sql-server-2017.aspx) function can be also used.
This thime the last select statement can be replaced with following SQL

```
select STRING_AGG(boundary, ', ')  Within Group (Order By grpno)
from fragments
```

Comment: The question turned out to be for Firebird, not SQL Server, so unfortunately this doesn't apply as Firebird doesn't have something like `stuff`.

Comment: Yes I understand, actually the last code using STUFF or STRING_AGG is just for concatenating strings, so it converts from rows to single column value

Comment: That effect could be achieved with Firebird's [`LIST`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-functions-aggfuncs.html#fblangref25-functions-aggfuncs-list), although that doesn't support a method to specify an order

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
SELECT ROWNUM FROM `your_table_name` WHERE ROWNUM IS NOT NULL ORDER BY ROWNUM DESC;
```

Comment: The result for your query will be like this " A6, A3, A2, A1 " rite?
but in my case the sequence from "A1 - A3" and the additional number "A6" will following at the end without following the sequence line. is it possible?

Comment: @BabySpring change "DESCENDING" to "ASCENDING" in the query above. And please read any ABC on SQL language, even Wikipedia would do here